# Java 8 - use stream to match all fields to either one of two values

Tags: java-8, java-stream

I have a list of states (enum: SomeStatus.class). I want to check if all states matches either FINISHED, PENDING, then I want to execute some condition.

```
public enum SomeStatus {
           FINISHED, PENDING, EMPTY, STARTED
}
```

Eg, this is how I would do for matching all states to one state. But how would I do it for matching it with 2 states (either / or) ?

```
if(states.stream().allMatch(SomeStatus.FINISHED::equals)) {
    // .... custom logic ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for example:

```java
        if(states.stream().allMatch(Set.of(SomeStatus.FINISHED, SomeStatus.PENDING)::contains)) {
            // .... custom logic ....
        }
```